# ID of drawable resources

Tags: android

How dynamically change position of drawable from android:drawableLeft to android:drawableRight/left/bottom ? 
I know, that I should use setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds method, but firstly I need to know R.drawable.*** and use it in setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds method.

```
private void changeLabelPosition(View view){
    int drawableID = 
    if(getGravity = Gravity.LEFT){
        view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableID, 0, 0, 0);
    }else if(getGravity = Gravity.TOP){
        view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, drawableID, 0 , 0);
    }else if(getGravity = Gravity.RIGHT){
        view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, drawableID, 0);
    }else if(getGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM){
        view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, drawableID);
    }    
}
```

so, I need the id of view`s drawable resource.

this way is not appropriate, cause there are many buttons, and it`s not good way to use hardcode:

```
drawableID = 0;
switch (view.getId()){
case R.id.button_add:
    drawableID = R.drawable.button_add;
case R.id.button_remove:
    drawableID = R.drawable.button_remove;
...
...
...
}
if(getGravity = Gravity.LEFT){
    view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableID, 0, 0, 0);
}
...
...
...
enter code here
```

**Edit**

```
switch (mMainPanelGravity)
 { 
case Gravity.TOP:
 for (View v : arrayOfViews)
 { 
Drawable[] drawables = ((TextView) v) .getCompoundDrawables();
 if (drawables.length != 0) { 
Drawable dr = drawables[0]; 
((TextView) v).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( null, dr, null, null); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom)` will also accept `Drawable`

you get `Drawable` of the the view and you can set it directly

```
Drawable drawable=yourview.getBackground();
```

and then

```
view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null)
```

**Edit:**

```
Drawable[] drawables = view.getCompoundDrawables()

if(drawables.length!=0)
{
Drawable drawable=drawable[0];
}
```

Comment: @user2038145 Not work in the sense, First make it clear what are you try to achieve

Comment: position of drawable is setting up from xml file as android:drawableRight.

Comment: still the same. text is in correct place, but drawable is not visible.

Comment: @user2038145 I really don't understand your problem. It will just get the drawable directly instead of id, nothing more than that..How is it differs from your code.?Please post your updated code

Comment: switch (mMainPanelGravity) {
   case Gravity.TOP:
    for (View v : arrayOfViews) {
     Drawable[] drawables = ((TextView) v)
       .getCompoundDrawables();

     if (drawables.length != 0) {
      Drawable dr = drawables[0];
      ((TextView) v).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
        null, dr, null, null);
     }

Comment: @user2038145 get the drawable outside of your switch condition and set the drawable according to the position